# Scroll up Relative Layout when scrolling up listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating an application. and the user information is shown in a relative layout. Under the relative layout is a listview with items the user created. I want if you scroll down in the List View that the Relative Layout scroll up and eventually disappeared, and the list view is stretched over the whole screen.

Like you have in de facebook app.
[Facebook Scrolling image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciZGx.jpg)

How do I do this, this is my layout file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/BackgroundPictureOther"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="#eeeeee" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileOther"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#444444"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1) You should put your entire layout inside NestedScrollView and change ListView into RecyclerView.

2) Or you can set your layout with profile picture as header view for listview. 
For this you need to put your layout with profile in other xml layout file, then inflate it in code and use listview.addHeaderView(view v)